# NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON with write access to SMB Share

Tags: server-message-block, windows-server-2019

I have just setup a fresh standalone Windows 2019 Server (Core) in a lab environment (i.e. for my own learning). In part, this is because I was interested in looking into null session configurations from a security perspective.

While doing this, I created a share that I intended to have write access from a null session. However, I am only able to get read access to that share, even when the `ANONYMOUS LOGON` is granted full access to both the share and shared directory ACLs.

I have noticed, when setting `EveryoneIncludesAnonymous` registry to `1`, I do get write access, however I dont understand why this is needed as I have explicitly already given `ANONYMOUS LOGON` full access.

Is there some additional check that is in-place I have missed? Any help would be appreciated in understanding this.

See command outputs below to see my configuration:

```perl
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-SmbShare -Name test1

Name  ScopeName Path                     Description
----  --------- ----                     -----------
test1 *         C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test1 anon share in iis root for testing

PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-SmbShareAccess -Name test1

Name  ScopeName AccountName                  AccessControlType AccessRight
----  --------- -----------                  ----------------- -----------
test1 *         NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON Allow             Full
test1 *         Everyone                     Allow             Full

PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-Acl C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test1\ | Format-List -Property Owner,AccessToString

Owner          : NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON
AccessToString : NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON Allow  FullControl
                 BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
                 BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS Allow  -1610612736
                 NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller Allow  FullControl
                 NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller Allow  268435456
                 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
                 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  268435456
                 BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
                 BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  268435456
                 BUILTIN\Users Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
                 BUILTIN\Users Allow  -1610612736
                 NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON Allow  FullControl
                 CREATOR OWNER Allow  268435456

PS C:\Users\Administrator> reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\system\currentcontrolset\control\lsa /v everyoneincludesanonymous

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\system\currentcontrolset\control\lsa
    everyoneincludesanonymous    REG_DWORD    0x0
```

Then trying to copy file to the share fails:

```
$ smbclient  -U '%' '\\192.168.56.20\test1'
Try "help" to get a list of possible commands.
smb: \> dir
  .                                   D        0  Fri Feb 28 08:21:29 2020
  ..                                  D        0  Fri Feb 28 08:21:29 2020
  somefile.txt                        A       22  Fri Feb 28 08:21:09 2020

                8247551 blocks of size 4096. 6341661 blocks available
smb: \> put test
NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED opening remote file \test
```

After setting `EveryoneIncludeAnonymous` to `0x1` it works. To me, this suggests there is some additional check performed by the `LanManServer`, but I dont know where.

```
$ smbclient  -U '%' '\\192.168.56.20\test1'
Try "help" to get a list of possible commands.
smb: \> put test
putting file test as \test (0.3 kb/s) (average 0.3 kb/s)
```

### EDIT (Update with registry values)

```
C:\Windows\system32>reg query hklm\system\currentcontrolset\control\lsa\

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\system\currentcontrolset\control\lsa
    auditbasedirectories    REG_DWORD    0x0
    auditbaseobjects    REG_DWORD    0x0
    Bounds    REG_BINARY    0030000000200000
    crashonauditfail    REG_DWORD    0x0
    fullprivilegeauditing    REG_BINARY    00
    LimitBlankPasswordUse    REG_DWORD    0x1
    NoLmHash    REG_DWORD    0x1
    Security Packages    REG_MULTI_SZ    ""
    Notification Packages    REG_MULTI_SZ    scecli
    Authentication Packages    REG_MULTI_SZ    msv1_0
    SecureBoot    REG_DWORD    0x1
    LsaPid    REG_DWORD    0x260
    LsaCfgFlagsDefault    REG_DWORD    0x0
    ProductType    REG_DWORD    0x7
    disabledomaincreds    REG_DWORD    0x0
    everyoneincludesanonymous    REG_DWORD    0x1
    forceguest    REG_DWORD    0x0
    restrictanonymous    REG_DWORD    0x0
    restrictanonymoussam    REG_DWORD    0x1
```

```
C:\Windows\system32>reg query hklm\system\currentcontrolset\services\lanmanserver\parameters

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\system\currentcontrolset\services\lanmanserver\parameters
    EnableAuthenticateUserSharing    REG_DWORD    0x0
    NullSessionPipes    REG_MULTI_SZ    
    ServiceDll    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %SystemRoot%\system32\srvsvc.dll
    ServiceDllUnloadOnStop    REG_DWORD    0x1
    autodisconnect    REG_DWORD    0xf
    enableforcedlogoff    REG_DWORD    0x1
    enablesecuritysignature    REG_DWORD    0x0
    requiresecuritysignature    REG_DWORD    0x0
    restrictnullsessaccess    REG_DWORD    0x1
    NullSessionShares    REG_MULTI_SZ    test1
    RejectUnencryptedAccess    REG_DWORD    0x1
    Guid    REG_BINARY    A8BD872570049045A692E9384049A8D1
```

Comment: What are the values of the other Windows security settings related to anonymous access?

Comment: @GregAskew - updated with registry values, they are essentially as they were when machine was installed

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable that in Group Policies.

`Network access: Let Everyone permissions apply to anonymous users`

in

*Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local
Policies\Security Options*

> Anonymous tokens do not include the Everyone Group SID unless the system default has been overridden by setting the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\EveryoneIncludesAnonymous` registry value to DWORD=1.

Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-impersonateanonymoustoken

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yep, from my limited understanding setting that in the GPO essentially sets the `EveryoneIncludeAnonymous` registry key (which is what I have set to get it working).

However, the nub of what I was trying to understand is why this is needed when I have explicitly assigned permissions for the anonymous logon?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: The link is nice but its relates more the the relationship between the everyone group and anonymous users. Not why when I grant an anonymous user full access do they only get read access (even when there are no explicit deny permissions for any SID).